# Kiss FFT thread safety

Tags: fft

I'm going to make several plans by [kiss-fft](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kissfft/) simultaneously (parallel), 
can I do that, or in another word , is kiss-fft thread safety ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

From README:

```
No static data is used.  The core routines of kiss_fft are thread-safe
```

Contrast to FFTW which requires mutex protection of the plan creation,destruction.

Also, if you are doing the same type,size of simple FFT (complex 1D) in multiple threads, an allocated plan may be used simultaneously.  This is not generally true for the real FFT and multi-dimensional FFTs.

Answer (score 0):

A brief survey of the Kiss FFT source reveals that it doesn't store state internally.  Just make sure the arrays you pass in and out are unique per thread or synchronized across threads.